# Disable Like button on Firebase Database reference listener in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a Like Button in my RecyclerView Item. Value is fetched from the firebase database reference listener. If "count" value is 1, the button should get disabled for that particular listitem and also turn its color to green. Here is the code:

```
//segregate email to userID
    String[] emailSegregate = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "anonymous").split("@");
    String emailID = emailSegregate[0];

    //Check username has liked the post already or not
    mMessagesDatabaseReferenceCheck
            .child(emailID)
            .child(objectFile.getnodeId())
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int b = 0;
                    check_counter objCheck = dataSnapshot.getValue(check_counter.class);
                    b = objCheck.getCount();
                    if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) { // TODO: write this condition
                        //make it green
                        btnLike.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        btnLike.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006400"));
                        btnLike.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else {}
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

Here is the Database:

[image]

Cant get one data from database and check the same on if Condition to disable a button for that particular nodeId listItem.

**Edited**

Here is the exception -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.abhin.myapplication, PID: 13674
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.abhin.myapplication.check_counter.getCounter()' on a null object reference
      at com.example.abhin.myapplication.postAdapter$2.onDataChange(postAdapter.java:148)
      at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Why not use your b variable: if (b == 1) { //disable button}

Comment: @Mr.O : Hi Mr.O, b value remains 0. :(

Comment: Are you sure objectFile.getnodeId() returns id in the screen shot of your database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    long count = dataSnapshot.child("count").getValue(Long.class);
    if (count > 0) {
        ...
```

Comment: Hi Frank, No. Rather it throws this error - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference

Comment: That seems unlikely with the code I shared. Can you edit your question to include the complete stack trace of that exception?

Comment: Added the exception.

Comment: As far as I can tell the code I shared does not raise that exception. What's on `postAdapter.java:148`? I'd also **highly** recommend studying [What is a `NullPointerException` and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), as it will help you with this and similar problems in the future.

Comment: Sure Frank. Always ready to learn and get better. Will read this stuff.